# Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context - Dokan Wordpress Plugin

Tags: wordpress, email, construct, dokan

I am receiving this error when using this code in my wordpress theme´s function.php

It seems the code has two parts, i think the last one must be inside the "construct function" but i don't know how to do it.

```
function order_email_include_saler_name( $order ) {
            $saler_id = dokan_get_seller_id_by_order( $order->id );
            $saler_info = get_user_by( 'id', $saler_id );

            ?>
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6" style="width: 100%; border: 1px solid #eee;" border="1" bordercolor="#eee">

                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row" style="text-align:left; width: 57%; border: 1px solid #eee; <?php  echo 'border-top-width: 4px;'; ?>"><?php _e( 'Saler Name:' ); ?></th>
                        <td style="text-align:left; border: 1px solid #eee; <?php  echo 'border-top-width: 4px;'; ?>"><?php echo $saler_info->display_name; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
            <?php
        }
```

And this is the construct function part:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', array( $this, 'order_email_include_saler_name' ) );
```

Please can anybody help? I have read all the posts with the same title, but I couldn´t understand how to continue. I am not a programmer and i don't understand coding.

Answer (score 0):

if your function is in your functions.php and not a method of any class, simply use the hook and the function name to hook as below:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', 'order_email_include_saler_name', 10, 1 );
```